# Displaying a description of a marshmallow Schema in OPTIONS method

Tags: python, rest, flask, marshmallow

I'm trying to implement a route in my flask application to serve the OPTIONS method of a given resource and return a description of the marshmallow schema associated to said resource. Something similar to what django does:

```
{
    "name": "Dataset List",
    "description": "",
    "renders": [
        "application/json",
        "text/html"
    ],
    "parses": [
        "application/json",
        "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "multipart/form-data"
    ],
    "actions": {
        "POST": {
            "id": {
                "type": "integer",
                "required": false,
                "read_only": true,
                "label": "ID"
            },
            "url": {
                "type": "field",
                "required": false,
                "read_only": true,
                "label": "Url"
            },
            "name": {
                "type": "string",
                "required": true,
                "read_only": false,
                "label": "Name",
                "help_text": "The dataset name.",
                "max_length": 256
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can't seem to find any method in `Schema` or in the docs that returns this description, and `AlbumSchema.opts.fields` is empty. Is it possible to iterate throughout the fields and build the description I need? Something in the line of:

```py
desc = {f: {"required": f.required,
            "type": f.__class__.__name__,
            ...}
        for f in AlbumSchema.fields}
```

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/marshmallow-code/apispec ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Pop I managed to find a solution.
First, I declared a generic options method:

```py
class DescriptiveMethodView(views.MethodView):
    name = description = uri = doc_uri = None

    def options(self, id=None):
        """Base Options View.
        ---
        description: retrieve options available for this resource.
        responses:
            200:
                name: description
                type: object
        """
        d = spec.to_dict()

        info = {'name': self.name,
                'description': self.description % {'id': id or 'model'}}

        return jsonify(info=info,
                       definitions=d['definitions'],
                       actions=d['paths'][self.doc_uri])
```

Then I just inherit from it and override those class attributes:

```py
class FooView(DescriptiveMethodView):
    name = 'Foos'
    description = 'all Foos in the dataset'
    doc_uri = uri = '/foo'


class BarView(DescriptiveMethodView):
    name = 'Bar'
    description = 'A bar in the dataset in the dataset'
    uri = '/bar/<id>'
    doc_uri = '/bar/{id}'
```